# Get a named cell from a named array range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named array of cells called `Cars` which runs from say `A1:B10`

Inside this I have a named cell called `Toyota` say at `A4` position.

So i do:

```
Private cars As Variant
cars = Range("Cars").Value

Dim toyota As String
toyota = cars.Range("Toyota").Value ???
```

I am a beginner in vba so excuse my novicity.

Comment: And what is the question excatly?  The first line already is wrong. The second line will not give you a single value instead it will give you an array and the last line just will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest a range within a range. You can address the Toyota range by qualifying it with the sheet name. The fact that there is an overlapping range called "cars" is totally irrelevant to addressing the "toyota" range.

Qualify the range with the sheet name, not the surrounding range name.

```
toyota = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("Toyota").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use @teylyn answer above.
2. If Range "Toyota" is always in Cell A4, while "Cars" Range is set to Range "A1:B10", you can use the following code to retrieve the value:

**Code**

```
Dim toyota As String
toyota = Range("Cars").Cells(4, 1).Value
```